# Problems with .net ValidateCredentials throwing an exception for any user other than Administrator

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server-2008

I have the following setup.

A Windows 2008 server that is NOT part of a domain but has many users configured locally on the machine (we are not using active directory).  I have an app running on another machine (currently Windows XP) on the network (also not part of a domain) that must validate whether a user has valid credentials on our 2008 server.

I've tried a bunch of different combinations but cannot get things to work and have run out of things to try.  I'm currently running the following code and can't figure out why it only works for the Administrator user.

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, "machineName");
//returns true
bool test1 = pc.ValidateCredentials("Administrator", "aValidPassword");
//returns false
bool test2 = pc.ValidateCredentials("Administrator", "anInvalidPassword");
//throws an exceptoin for any valid username/password combination I send
bool test3 = pc.ValidateCredentials("anotherUser", "aValidPassword");
```

The above code works correctly when trying to validate the Administrator but if I try and validate ANY other user on that machine I get the following exception.

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: General access denied error
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UnsafeNativeMethods.IADs.Get(String bstrName)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.CredentialValidator.BindSam(String target, String userName, String password)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.CredentialValidator.Validate(String userName, String password)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials(String userName, String password)
```

I should also mention that "anotherUser" is also an administrator on the 2008 server.  Why is it that only the Administrator user can be validated?  I've tried a few different non-Administrator accounts and none of them work.  I know for sure the username/password that I am using is valid and that the users are not disabled or anything like that.  I'm not having any luck googling for a solution, possibly because this should be so simple, I must be missing something blatantly obvious...  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(Edited to add the following paragraph)

I still haven't figured this problem out but thought I'd follow up in hopes someone would help, I'm at a loss.  It's very strange what is happening.  I'm looking at the Event Viewer->Windows Logs->Security to see if it would help point to the problem.  The odd thing is that in the those logs everything is reported as a success and there are no problems indicated.  Despite that, I'm still getting the UnauthorizedAccessException with message "General access denied error" on my C# client.  I also noticed that the source of the exception is "Active Directory" despite this fact that we are not using active directory (the server isn't even on a domain, it's only on a workgroup).  Does anyone know how I could possibly getting success logs in the Event Viewer but yet I'm still getting exceptions within the client?

(Edited to add the following paragraph)

Intresting, if I call ValidateCredentials with an invalid password for my "anotherUser" account it doesn't throw the exception and correctly returns false.  It continues to throw the exception when the password is correct though.  Does anyone know Why would this be?  This makes no sense at all and I really don't want to have to depend on this strange behaviour, I want to know why the successful call is throwing an exception and fix the root cause...

Thanks!

(edited to correct error where I said the third call returns false when it actually throws an exception)

Comment: Have you verified that 'another user' exists the machine the code is being executed on, and that the password is valid?  Is the account locked out?  also, can you provide the exception text and the inner exception text if it exists.

Comment: The code is being executed on the XP machine so 'anotherUser' doesn't exist on that box, but it does exist on the 2008 server.  The password is correct and the user isn't locked out or disabled.  I'm able to login to the machine directly with the 'anotherUser' UN/PW combination.  I've also tried multiple users and all of them (other than Administrator) have the same problem.  Stack Trace coming.

Comment: I still haven't figured out this problem, if anyone has any information that would lead me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you login to the xp machine with the 'anotheruser' account?

Comment: I've tried creating 'anotherUser' on my XP machine with the same password as the user on the 2008 server and it didn't make a difference, it still fails with the exception mentioned above.  I've also tried without 'anotherUser' existing on my XP machine and it fails as well.  My required functionality is to not have the user programmed locally though, but I thought I'd try as many combinations as I can to try and figure out exactly what is going on.  Perhaps what I'm trying to do just isn't possible with a SAM store...